# delay on back button pressed android

Tags: android, tabs

I have a problem with one of my activities when the back button is pressed. The problem is a long delay and no "back animation". The activity in question has a blank layout so far but it is started from another activity in a tab.

I've tried to research this issue but most of what I've seen has revolved around trying to have multiple activities within a single tab. This does not apply here as **I do** want the activity in question to cover the tabs. I do not have much to go on since the app does not crash and there are no logs. My assumption is that it has something with stating an activity from another that is a tab.

If anyone has seen this issue before please let me know.

Thanks

Edit : CODE

```
public class QuizMenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

int ID_playBtn = 11;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_menu_layout);
    Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    playBtn.setId(ID_playBtn);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Play
    if(v.getId()==ID_playBtn){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.rbi.mshdictionary.QuizActivity");
        startActivity(intent); 
    }

}
```

}

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity{

VideoView videoView;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_layout);
}
```

}

```
public class TabMainActivity extends TabActivity{


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_main_layout);

    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LearnActivity.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Learn").setIndicator("Learn",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_learn))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, QuizMenuActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Quiz").setIndicator("Quiz",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_quiz))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you fetching any data from webserver while you are navigating the screen?

Comment: Plz make ur question more clear dear.... If possible, just post ur code.. And let others to know what ur problem...

Comment: have you used any thread ??? put some code here so we can get some idea

Comment: No I'm not doing anything as of yet. The problem activity is started when a button is pressed (in one of the tab activities) and it has a blank layout as its content. This is why I haven't posted any code as there is nothing but code to transition between the two activities.

Comment: Here's the code, I'm new to the tabhost and am pretty much just copying an example found online. The quizMenuActivity is a tab and starts the quizActivity (which covers tabs)... when back is pressed there's a long pause and then the tabs suddenly come back instead of the standard slide animation that usually happens when transitioning  between activities. I also noticed that if I click the other tab after this happens that the animation happens on the transition between tabs (which doesn't happen by any other time). Hope this is more clear!

Answer (score 2):

When you have clicked on the ID_playBtn , TabMainActivity is not destroyed and stay at the background.

When you are pressing back button, quizActivity is getting destroyed and TabMainActivity comes to foreground(so no slide animation as that activity is not starting but coming to foreground) then onResume() function (could be the reason for long pause) of your TabMainActivity gets called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not really clear on what your explanation is for the long pause but what I tried was to finish the tabMainActivity when onPause() is called then override the onbackpressed() in the quiz activity in order to start the tabMainActivity over again. If anyone looks at this and has a better idea on how to handle it (as I do not think that it is the most elegant of solutions) please post! Thanks you all for your help.

Comment: may be this is where you are wrong. tabMainActivity is already at the background and there is no need to override the onbackpressed(). Try not to finish it on onPause() and don't override onbackpressed() and , it may work fine. If not, if you could share your project files with me , I will fix it for you. I will not leave you hanging . n wish you a very happy new year !